# Evento não é disparado no Safari mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

Tenho essa div em meu Html, quando clicada, abre o explorador de arquivos, através do [Plupload](https://www.plupload.com/), para fazer o upload de um pdf:

```html
<div @(Convert.ToInt32(documento.CodDocumento) > 0 ? "style=display:none" : "") class="ui compact icon button green btn-enviar-arquivos btn-doc-obrigatorio" id="btn-enviar-@documento.CodTipoDocumento" onclick="void(0);" tabindex="0" title="Anexar">
  <i class="upload icon"></i>
</div>
```

A classe `btn-enviar-arquivos` é usada pelo Plupload como o ouvinte para abrir o explorados de arquivos do SO. E a classe `btn-doc-obrigatorio` é usada como um ouvinte de clique para executar algumas ações:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-doc-obrigatorio', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var tipo = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-tipo]').text();
  $('#hdnCodTipoDoc').val(tipo);
  $('#hdnTipoDocObrigatorio').val(1);
});
```

Tudo isso funciona perfeitamente em todos os navegadores, inclusive no Safari. No entanto, o ouvinte de evento da classe `btn-doc-obrigatorio` não é disparado no Safari na versão mobile. O que pode estar acontecendo para ele não ser disparado apenas nesse ambiente?

Comment: Pq a div tem esse `onclick="void(0);"`? Já testou sem ele?

Comment: Já testei sim. Usei ele pelo fato de vários lugares aconselharem colocar esse `onclick="void(0)"` por conta do Safari mobile

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema criando uma `div` pai, e então movi a classe `btn-doc-obrigatorio`, responsável por disparar o evento, para a nova `div`.

```html
<div class="btn-doc-obrigatorio">
  <div @(Convert.ToInt32(documento.CodDocumento) > 0 ? "style=display:none" : "") class="ui compact icon button green btn-enviar-arquivos" id="btn-enviar-@documento.CodTipoDocumento" onclick="void(0);" tabindex="0" title="Anexar">
    <i class="upload icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```